# How to filter group by results by set

Tags: mysql

I would like to make a sql request of this kind (this not work):

```
SELECT a, ... FROM tb WHERE ... GROUP BY a HAVING INTERSECTION(b, ('foo', 'bar')) is empty
```

I do not know how to do the 'INTERSECTION(b, ('foo', 'bar')) is empty' part. I want to not match any row whose set of 'b' fields intersected with a fixed set (here ('foo', 'bar')) is empty. The only solution I found so far is:

```
SELECT a, ... FROM tb WHERE ... and a not in (select a from tb where b in ('foo', 'bar')) GROUP BY a
```

But this request is very slow (the table has +2M rows). Is there a better way to do the same thing? I think I could use HAVING to filter results but I don't see how.

EDIT: add example:

For example if I have:

```
a    b
1    'foo'
1    'test'
2    'test'
3    'bar'
```

Only row a=2 should be returned since one of a=1 contains 'foo'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT a, ..., sum(if(b in ("foo", "bar"), 1, 0)) as fooBarCount FROM tb WHERE ... GROUP BY a HAVING fooBarCount < 1;
```

Here's [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33d5b/1/0)

Comment: This does not work because if there is, for a = 1, two rows, one with b = 'test' and another with b = 'foo', the first one will be taken and   a = 1 will be in the resultset. But If at least one of the b associated with a contains one of the fixed list, I want to exclude it

Comment: This work, thank you. But is is slower than the request with the subselect in my question. I don't exactly understand why, I though it would be faster.

Comment: Do you have index on a?

Comment: Yes(primary key). I do not have index on b but I could use another field c instead of b which is integer and in the primary key (I prefer using b because it is more meaningful, but i can also use c). I tried the request with c instead of b, it is a bit faster. The subquery request is about 2.5 times faster than the one with having

Comment: This just shot in dark but having can be the culprit if subset is too big. Just try with group by if is fast the we can try subquery join.

Comment: I will accept your answer since I asked if it was possible to do with having. But I will use the subquery I posted in the question finally since it is faster.